# How to identify a clob contains a single json object or an array of json object

Tags: json, plsql

I have a clob data type, some time return a single json object:

```
{
  "data1" : "xxxxxx",
  "data2" : "xxxxxx"
}
```

sometimes return an array of json objects:

```
[{
  "data1" : "xxxxxx",
  "data2" : "xxxxxx"
},
.....
{
  "data1" : "xxxxxx",
  "data2" : "xxxxxx"
}]
```

How can I identify them and use json_array_t or json_object_t appropriately?
Is there a simple if condition can apply?

Answer (score 0):

If your sample data is accurate then I would just use dbms_lob.substr to get the first character and if it is a square bracket then you have multiple otherwise you have a single....

more information on dbms_lob package here (happens to be 10g doco, but don't think it has changed but confirm for your version of Oracle if needed)
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349

so you would end up with logic something like the below

```
 select dbms_lob.substr(*your lob here*, 1, 1)
 into v_whaterver
 from dual;

 If v_whatever = '[' THEN 
   --you have multiple
 ELSE 
   -- you have single
 END IF;
```